# Kubeadm Kubernetes cluster cannot map External IP address to domain name using ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, dns, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to setup a Kubernetes cluster using `Kubeadm` in GCE. I was able to access the deployment using a `Nodeport` service from the external IP. I am trying to set up an ingress that maps to a domain name but was not able to do it. So far what I have done:

- Created a [baremetal nginx ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#bare-metal) (I am using `kubeadm`)
- Created a `Nodeport` service on the deployment (was able to connect it **from the outside of the cluster**)
- Created an ingress resource using the configuration below:
  and the command `kubectl describe ingress my-ingress` returns
  `my-ingress   <none>   sample.com   10.160.15.210   80, 443   32h` which is the **internal IP**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    ingressClassName: nginx
    
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - sample.com
    secretName: sample-tls
  rules:
  - host: sample.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: sample # the nodeport service name of the deployment
            port: 
              number: 8000 # nodeport target port
```

I cannot access the deployment using `sample.com` . I double checked the DNS name,  using the command `dig sample.com` and it returns the **external IP**.

Answer (score 0):

If you created your cluster using GCP, you should have used [GCE-GKE](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke) installation instructions.

Important difference is that *GCE-GKE* installation creates `LoadBalancer` instead of `NodePort`

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Yeah, I could map it to externally using a `LoadBalancer`. The setup is not yet completed because i can only access the server using `sample.com:<port>`. I believe i need a `external LoadBalancer` to complete the setup